Need to plot the graph and label side by side in a frame
def predict_score(name):
root =  CTk()
root.geometry("1200x600")
frame = CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(side="left", expand=True, padx=(10, 5))

graph_frame = CTkFrame(master=root)
graph_frame.pack(side="left", expand=True, padx=(5, 10))

new_movie = movies[movies['original_title'].str.contains(name)].iloc[0].to_frame().T

print('Selected Movie:', new_movie.original_title.values[0])

def Similarity(movie1_id, movie2_id):
    return 0

def getNeighbors(baseMovie, K):
    distances = []

    for index, movie in movies.iterrows():
        if movie['new_id'] != baseMovie['new_id'].values[0]:
            dist = Similarity(baseMovie['new_id'].values[0], movie['new_id'])
            if dist is not None:
                distances.append((movie['new_id'], dist))

    distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    neighbors = []

    for x in range(K):
        neighbors.append(distances[x])
    return neighbors

K = 10
avgRating = 0
neighbors = getNeighbors(new_movie, K)

recommended_movies_label = CTkLabel(master=frame, font=("Arial", 18), text="Recommended Movies : ")
recommended_movies_label.pack(anchor="w", pady=30, padx=50)

recommended_titles = [movies.iloc[neighbor[0]]['original_title'] for neighbor in neighbors]

labels = recommended_titles
sizes = np.random.randint(1, 100, len(labels))
colors = plt.cm.tab20.colors[:len(labels)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
ax.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=140, colors=colors)
ax.axis('equal')

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=graph_frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

for neighbor in neighbors:
    movie_info = movies.iloc[neighbor[0]]
    movie_label = CTkLabel(master=frame, font=("Arial", 14), text=movie_info[0] + " | Genres : " +
                                  str(movie_info[1]).strip('[]').replace(' ', '') +
                                  " | Rating : " + str(movie_info[2]))
    movie_label.pack(anchor="w", padx=50)

    avgRating += movie_info[2]

avg_rating_btn = CTkButton(master=frame, text="Average Rating: " + str(avgRating / K), corner_radius=8)
avg_rating_btn.pack(pady=30)

root.mainloop()

this is the full code
i wanted to implement the graph side by side of the recommended movies frame but it seems the titles are just cropping out of the frame
heres the image
also when i close my application i seem to get an error and my terminal is stuck in a loop
Selected Movie: Avatar
invalid command name "2921325108160update"
while executing
"2921325108160update"
("after" script)
invalid command name "2921325107008check_dpi_scaling"
while executing
"2921325107008check_dpi_scaling"
("after" script)
